# White space appears when responsive website is resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, viewport, wow.js

I have a responsive website using bootstrap in which almost every element animates in with WOWjs (animates in as you scroll by it.) When I resize the document to test its responsiveness then scroll all the way down, then open it up in full screen, I'm way under the footer. I inspected the element and that white space isn't part of anything. Not even the body. In fact, I can't highlight it and it appears under the body element. I'm very confused by this. It may be WOWjs because I have encountered similar things while using WOWjs in other projects. Removing WOWjs is not an option as this is for a client and he wants it. I have tried adding `height: 100%` and this results in WOWjs elements to not fade in. I have also tried `margin: 0; 
padding: 0;` and it still doesn't work. I can't attach the code because it requires way too much assets and its over 300 codes and I don't know where the problem is. I can give you some code that may, or atleast i think may, be relevant.

```
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```

Maybe someone has background on WOWjs and animatecss and viewport to resolve the problem.

PS.. The website is a php document as it has a contact form.

Comment: The code you have posted here is not enough to go on. What you should do is take the resulting HTML (with View Source in the browser) and then edit that to remove everything that does not contribute to the problem. What you will have left is what you should post here for us to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should write you wow js code in

```
$(window).load(function(){
// your wow js code //call here your code
});
```

hope you will get your solutions